# Improper Integral from Gradshteyn and Ryzhik

Tags: improper-integrals, integration

This is the integral one can find in the Introduction of 'Special Integrals of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik the Proofs - Volume I' by Victor H. Moll:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^{3/2} \left[ \phi(x) + \sqrt{\phi(x)} \right]^{1/2}}, \quad \phi(x) = 1 + \frac{4x^2}{3(1+x^2)^2} \;.$$
The author doesn't know the final answer.
It is claimed that it is $\pi / 2 \sqrt{6}$, though numerical integration contradicts this.

Any ideas how to solve it or where to find clues?

Comment: This is a weird question, but it could be interesting if we knew where does this beast come from...Otherwise it just looks like an exercise made up by someone getting bored bad.

Comment: I agree with you that there is a problem somewhere since numerical integration leads to $0.66637711426883385640$ and inverse symbolic calculators do not find anything.

Comment: The $4/3$ ratio hints that the triple angle formula might come at play. Hence i would make a hyperbolic substitution and adjust the function $\phi(x)$ accordingly. I'll try that when i get home.

Comment: the conjectured closed form seems to be not correct :(

Comment: I have not been able to find the book you refer to. Could you e-mail a copy of this page (my address is in my profile). Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici [Here is the googlebooks preview of this book](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=8ZPSBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&hl=iw&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: @nospoon. Thanks for that. In the seventh edition of the book, this integral does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, I worked numerically$$I(k)=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{dx}{\left(x^2+1\right)^{3/2} \sqrt{\phi (x)+\sqrt{\phi (x)}}}\qquad, \qquad \phi(x) = 1 + \frac{kx^2}{(1+x^2)^2}
   $$ and tried to find $k$ such that $$I(k)=\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{6}}$$ The closest value I found is $k_*=0.5923509316314110643$ which inverse symbolic calculators did not find any equivalent. $$I(k_*)\approx 0.6412749150809320477747$$ $$\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{6}}\approx0.6412749150809320477720$$